# Highlighting text

Tags: jquery, css

I have to highlight the word passed in by the user. I use the below code to identify the presence of the word in a given sentence and then if present I display the entire sentence.

```
<html>
```

Example

```
<style type="text/css">
  .highlight{
    color: maroon;
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getSentence(word) {
var sentence="here is the text";
alert(word);
if (sentence.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase())!=-1) {
    sentence.replace(new RegExp('\b(word)\b', 'g'), '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
    $("#placeholder").append("<h3>"+sentence+"</h3><br/>");

    }
    }
</script>
```

```
<form>
  <div>
    <a onclick=getSentence('text');>text</a>
  </div>
   <div id="placeholder"></div>
</form>
```

Please let me know how to highlight the given word in sentence.

Answer (score 2):

```
sentence.replace(new RegExp('\b(word)\b', 'g'), '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
```

This assumes your text has no HTML in it. If it does, we need to look for text nodes recursively and apply the regex.

Comment: @dazzle `$1` is the back reference to the first capturing group.

Comment: function getSentence(word) {
 var sentence="here is the word";
 if (sentence.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase())!=-1) {
 sentence.replace(new RegExp('\b(word)\b', 'g'), '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
        $("#placeholder").append("<h3>"+sentence+"</h3><br/>");
  
        }
  }
    </script>

Comment: @dazzle Please edit that into your original question, if you can't be bothered making it readable I can't be bothered helping :)

Comment: Thanks, I tried as shown above. But it didn't work :( Can you pls tell me what wrong.

Comment: @dazzle Go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5415076/edit) and place that new code into your question (don't forget to mark it up with code with the `{ }` button).

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try this as per your requirement

[Highlight](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html)